# Differentiating Integral using Leibniz rule

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I am confronted with the following problem:

$$ V(t) = \pi \int_t^\infty e^{-\bar{r}(t,v)(v-t)}dv,$$

with $\pi$ constant and $\bar{r}(v,t) = \frac{1}{v-t} \int_t^v r(\omega)d\omega$.

I am looking for the derivative of $V(t)$ with respect to $t$, $\dot{V(t)}$.

Apparently, using the Leibniz rule, this should yield:

$$\dot{V(t)} = V(t)r(t) - \pi \Leftrightarrow r(t) = \frac{\pi}{V(t)} + \frac{\dot{V(t)}}{V(t)}$$

I have tried the following:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dV}{dt}  & = \pi \int_t^\infty \frac{d}{dt} e^{- \int_t^v r(\omega)d\omega}dv \\
 &= \pi \int_t^\infty \frac{d}{dt} e^{ \int_v^t r(\omega)d\omega}dv \\
 &= \pi \int_t^\infty r(t) e^{-\int_t^vr(\omega)d\omega}dv \\
 &= \pi r(t) \int_t^\infty e^{-\int_t^vr(\omega)d\omega}dv \\
\dot{V(t)} &= r(t)V(t)
\end{align}
$$

This obviously doesn't match but I don't know where I am wrong.
How do I properly solve this problem?

Comment: You also add an extra term $-\pi e^{-\int_t^t r(w)dw} = -\pi$ because of the variable limit $t$.

Comment: I agree with [George](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/658818/george-dewhirst). The Leibniz rule consists of three parts, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Comment: Thank you @GeorgeDewhirst, this appears to get me to the correct solution. However, what isn't clear to me is how to properly apply the Leibniz rule to this problem, i.e. how to get the parts of the Leibniz rule including the new integral limits.

Comment: Here $b(t) = \infty$, $\frac{d}{dt}b(t)=0$, $a(t)=t$, $\frac{d}{dt}a(t)=1$.

We get $r(t)V(t)+f(t,\infty)*0-f(t,t)$

Where $f(t,v) = \pi e^{\int_t^{v}r(\omega)d\omega}$. You can see $f(t,t) = \pi$.

Comment: Thank you so much, this made it clear.